# Packery Margin out of nowhere

Tags: css, packery

Okay mates. Basically, when using the code below, I load the page and there is margin between the .item divs. However, when I resize the window the margin disappears.

I've no idea why.
I don't want a margin.

Here is a codepen.io http://codepen.io/Ralphunter/pen/bNqwEX

```css
 body {
     padding:           0;
     margin:            0;
 }
 .item {
     background-color:  #40152A;
     width:             25%;
    
     padding-bottom: 25%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="http://packery.metafizzy.co/packery.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" class="js-packery" data-packery-options='{ "gutter": 0 }'>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a codepen.io http://codepen.io/Ralphunter/pen/bNqwEX

Comment: I don't know packery but I can see that the margins are created by the absolute positioning.

Comment: The margins are due to the presence of the vertical scrollbar. Without the scrollbar, everything fits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is caused by a missing scrollbar when initializing Packery. Add to your CSS:

```
html { overflow-y: scroll }
```

(from here: https://github.com/metafizzy/packery/issues/68)

Comment: Sorted pal. I opened a ticket also.  [https://github.com/metafizzy/packery/issues/233](https://github.com/metafizzy/packery/issues/233)